# how to know the change in objects in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

I am bit new to objective c frameworks. I want to detect the change in objects(the values of its instance variables). Do I have some readymade solution given by objective c?
Any Api for that OR Do I need to have my own implementations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is something called [Key Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

But you cannot detect the change of a C-variable.

However you can observe a change of an object's internal state. For this you have to get the property accessed by `self.property`, directly accessing the property like `_property=something` bypasses the KVO.